# PHP SQL statement escaping

Tags: php, mysql, sql, escaping

I wanted to show each user where they called using this statement:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `CallerNumber`, `CalleeNumber`, `ServiceCost` FROM `calls` WHERE `Customer_ID` = $current_user['CustomerID']");
```

The `$current_user['CustomerID']` part is causing the error. I tried to put it inside single quotes with / escapes, but it didn't work. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this below.

```
$arg = $current_user['CustomerID'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `CallerNumber`, `CalleeNumber`, `ServiceCost` FROM `calls` WHERE `Customer_ID` = '$arg'");
```

Comment: -1, fail. If `$arg` is a string a space will break this code. If `$current_user['customerID']` can a manipulated by a user you have an SQL-injection. Very poor code.

Comment: @Johan .. you are right but my goal was to solve the error and get the code working first. I didn't want to start preaching security and best practices. :)

Comment: @scartag, an answer that does not address this issue is worse than useless, it is dangerous. the #1 security threat (OK #2, see: http://blogs.oracle.com/carolmcdonald/entry/owasp_top_10_number_2 ) This has been #1/#2 it varies for many many years.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I did PHP, but I think what you need is this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `CallerNumber`, `CalleeNumber`, `ServiceCost` FROM `calls` WHERE `Customer_ID` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($current_user['CustomerID']) . "'");
```

(I just looked up `mysql_real_escape_string`, apologies if it's not the commonly used one.)

Also, escaping is done with a backslash (\), not a forward slash (/)

Comment: -1, but almost, you need to always surround injected values with single quotes, or mysql_real_escape_string() will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The only proper answer is:

First escape the parameter if it was not generated by the program itself.
It a good idea to always! escape vars you are going in inject into a query.
It's an even better idea to use PDO, but that another subject.

```
$arg = mysql_real_escape_string($current_user['CustomerID']);
```

Then surround the injected var with single quotes **or the escaping will not work!**

```
$query = "SELECT CallerNumber, CalleeNumber, ServiceCost 
          FROM calls WHERE Customer_ID = '$arg' ");
```

This will also prevent a syntax error in your SQL statement if `$var` contains a space  or other specials vars.

Backticks around columnnames are not needed, unless you are using a reserved word for a column name,  <sub>or you are using spaces or other strange characters in your column/table names</sub>

Comment: Oh, ok. The parameter is generated by the program, database, and I am fetching it. If I was getting it from the user, I would escape it. Thanks

Comment: @Cimborn, I'm confused, you ask about `escaping` but when I answer the escaping part, you don't want to know about escaping. Anyway my point is, if you are not using PDO you should always escape, because things change and data that comes from inside the program **right now** may see a code refactoring tomorrow where the data comes from the user. Also users have access to way more data than many programmers realize.

Comment: @Cimbom, I know you didn't downvote, because that would be impossible with 1 rep. Some people get upset when you downvote them and revenge downvote you back, no biggy but sometimes it's nice to know what reason real downvoters have to mark your question as not useful. Some of my most enlighting moments on SO have come as a result of the downvote explanation. Downvoting without stating why is just silly, because there's no chance to learn.

Comment: @Johan I honestly think you deserve an upvote. Your answer is obviously the best one here. +1 from me :)

Comment: None other than the guys who attack websites with injections would downvote it :D so, yeah.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `{$current_user['CustomerID']}` instead of `$current_user['CustomerID']`

Only use this in case `$current_user['CustomerID']` is not a user input, otherwise you should use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to avoid [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Now I am using this answer. Is this prone to SQL injection too?

Comment: {} don't work as you think they do with `mysql_real_escape_string()` you need to use single quotes instead. This will leave you wide open.

Comment: See http://codepad.org/cM9V2YX4 for a demo on how this will fail if `$current_user['CustomerID']` has a space in it.

Answer (score -1):

For variables (including arrays and even attribute calls from objects) in double quotes or heredocs (EOT), just enclose them in curly braces.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `CallerNumber`, `CalleeNumber`, `ServiceCost` FROM `calls` WHERE `Customer_ID` = {$current_user['CustomerID']}");
```

Comment: @Johan I'm answering his question based on what is his problem. But I agree with you that building an SQL string without cleaning it is a bad practice because it is prone to SQL injection. Though given the context of his problem, it is unknown where $current_user came from thus we can't conclude the code is bad.

Comment: The {} will not work when the $current_user.... contains a space, see http://codepad.org/cM9V2YX4 For demonstration on why it will not work

Comment: @Johan Thanks for the comment! This will only work if `{$current_user['CustomerID']}` is a number. If you're expecting a string with or without spaces, this will give you a bug.